# Replicate wp_list_categories with get_categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks in advance.

I have searched high and low for a solution but just can't find it, surely it's simpler than I think? Basically I need to replicate the output of wp_list_categories and change the `<a href="">` to include a data-filter on the child categories. I can do this with no issues for the parent categories, however I can't seem to output the children categories also.

Is there any way to even add a data-filter to the outputted `<a href="">` instead of replicating the entire output?

This is my code so far, which only outputs the parent categories.

```
<ul id="ondemandNav">
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'categoriestest',
                        'parent' => 0,
                        'hide_empty' => 0
                    );

                    $categories = get_categories($args);
                    $catid = array();
                     foreach($categories as $category)  {

                         echo '<li class="parent-item"><a href="">' . $category->name . '</a> .';

                         echo '</li>';
                         array_push($catid, $category->term_id);

                    } ?>
                </ul>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll need a second loop to pick up the children and grandchildren. I've not actually tried this code but it looks like it should work according to the `get_categories()` Codex page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

```
<ul id="ondemandNav">
<?php $args = array('taxonomy'   => 'categoriestest',
                    'parent'     => 0,
                    'hide_empty' => 0 );

$categories = get_categories($args);
$catid = array();

foreach($categories as $category)  {
    $child_args = array('child_of'=> $category->term_id); 
    $child_categories = get_categories($args);
    echo '<li class="parent-item"><a href="">' . $category->name . '</a> .</li>';

    foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) {
        echo '<li class="parent-item"><a href="">' . $child_category->name . '</a> .</li>';

    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Since it says it fetches children **and** grandchildren, I am guessing that you do not need a recursive method to drill all the way down to the bottom.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Hi Cal, Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work however. I've tried various combinations but it is outputting 1 parent then all children, not related to that parent. Then repeats for every parent. Nothing is nested either. Hmm...

Comment: With a minor few tweaks I got this script working as I wished. The above script will work for anyone else, if you just change "$child_categories = get_categories($args);"  to  "$child_categories = get_categories($child_args);" Many thanks for your help.